# Connection between canonical correlation and distribution of roots of characteristic equation

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, eigenvalues, canonical-correlation

I'm trying to make sense of the following sentence from introduction "Multiple discoveries: Distribution of roots of determinantal equations"
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/ted/papers/2007_MultipleDiscoveries.pdf

"The distribution of the squares of the canonical correlations when the population canonical correlations are zero is the same as the distribution of the characteristic roots of one sample covariance matrix in the metric of another."

I'm taking this to mean that it's talking about the distribution of the following random variable, where $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

$$\left(\frac{\langle X,Y\rangle}{\|X\|\|Y\|}\right)^2$$

Can anyone help me understand why the distribution of this variable is connected to distribution of characteristic roots?